# Difference between WATIN and WATIR

Tags: c#, ruby, watir, watin

Can any one suggest which one is best practise to do `webautomation`, `WATIN/WATIR`?

Am not familiar with `ruby`, but having knowledge in `.net`

I need to test the applications, which all comes under `frames`.

Please post idea and difference on both!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer .net, then [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) or [WatiN](http://watin.org/) would be a better choice than [Watir](http://watir.com/) ([Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/)). All of them do pretty much the same thing, automate browsers.